# is this possible: Amps feed joining a Regulated V line

Tags: voltage, connector, amperage

As we all know linear regulators cannot handle a lot of amperage and tend to waste a lot of energy, so I was thinking if it is possible to create a regulated output then put the amperage after the regulation...

A slight demonstration of a schematic to show what I mean:

[image: http://s12.postimg.org/4o21xqvg9/2015_06_29_21_15_07.jpg]

Is this possible? If yes is there a schematic I can look at? What should I look for?

sorry for the bad picture, I tried to make it better but failed..

--Edit--
I'm not trying get my circuit to work, just to convey the meaning.. I know this circuit won't work the way I want it, it is just an illustration.

Comment: Not really, no.  The way to get around the limitations of linear regulators is by using switching regulators.

Comment: "Amps" are not separate things you can add to "volts".

Comment: Well a 50A regulator is NOT going to be easy nor cheap.. >.< isn't it possible to be merged at all? What about Amp sources?

Comment: Is your idea to waste some of the power in resistors rather than the pass transistor (total will be about the same since it's still a linear regulator)? It's possible, but think about what happens if the load is too light- the output voltage will rise out of regulation.

Comment: @Nick Johnson It's not adding but kind of merging the high current low voltage line to a regulated line

Comment: @Pefhany the resistors at the top are just too equally divided the high amperage through multiple lines of necessary, it's just a route for the amperage to go through rather than going through the linear regulator

Comment: The trick is to reduce the voltage accross the regulator to just above its drop out voltage. Not sure about the 50A requirement, but something like that can be accomplished with a low frequency switch that charges an capacitor through an inductor. Or a phase controlled pre-regulator. http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an2f.pdf

Comment: @bakriawad I'm afraid that doesn't make any sense. :)

Comment: @Nick Johnson it is because I can't make a good sense of it that I asked, it seemed wrong yet logical enough. so far it seems far fetched, but I know there is a way, there is always a way! And I will find it at some point.

Comment: @bakriawad I'm afraid Ohm's law states that there isn't a way: without reactive components you cannot convert down in voltage without wasting the difference in heat.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid Electricity Doesn't Work That Way. A linear regulator is basically a resistor that varies its resistance based on the load drawn, to always keep a consistent voltage. In parallel with that you've put some resistors (and note, multiple parallel resistors are equivalent to one resistor with 1/nth the resistance).

What will actually happen in your circuit is this: if the load is large, current will be drawn via your extra resistors until the voltage across them is such that the side closest to the load is at the voltage provided by the voltage regulator. Any additional current will be drawn through the voltage regulator. Together, your resistors and the voltage regulator will dissipate exactly as much waste power (and heat) as a regulator alone would.

If the load is small, the voltage across your resistors will be small, and the voltage on the output will thus be large - up to the input voltage minus the diode's forward voltage, at no load - and the linear regulator will shut off completely, vainly trying to reduce the voltage by limiting the current through it.

Thus, what you've created is a sort of "lower bound voltage regulator", which provides a voltage between the input voltage and the set voltage at low currents, and exactly the set voltage at high currents, up to the limit of what your regulator plus resistors can dissipate.

There are well established solutions for converting voltages at high current with low waste, called switching regulators. They work by repeatedly charging up an inductor - a coil of wire - and discharging it into a capacitor, which serves to convert from one voltage to another with minimal waste.

Comment: That was very informative, but you got part of the point wrong.. the point is making a cheap high amperage regulator, I can just put 20 12V regulators and get upto 30A capability, but 20 regulators is expensive and need more resources, unlike what it could be like in the schematic that I provided.  But it seems not possible

Comment: @bakriawad 20 linear regulators will be just as inefficient as 1 with correct heatsinking - and a whole lot more expensive than just using a switching regulator, the correct solution to this problem.

Comment: I know that, and 1 can not handle 10A even with a great heatsink, you'd need liquid cooling artis alread alread at least.. I am trying to think outside the box.. it seems that this is not possible I guess.. it's an idea not a need